# How do I add python-contextlib to python_2.7.3.bbappend?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bitbake, openembedded

In my `custom-layer/recipes-devtools/python/python_2.7.3.bbappend`, I have the following contents

```
PROVIDES+="${PN}-contextlib "

PACKAGES+="${PN}-contextlib "

SUMMARY_${PN}-contextlib="Python utilities for with-statementcontexts."
RDEPENDS_${PN}-contextlib="${PN}-core "
FILES_${PN}-contextlib="${libdir}/python2.7/contextlib.* "

RDEPENDS_${PN}-modules+= "${PN}-contextlib "
```

When I execute `bitbake -f python-contextlib` - nothing fails.

When I add python-contextlib as a RDEPEND within another recipe, it fails as in “no package provides python-contextlib” when the `do_rootfs` task is executed.

When I build python, I do see the file contextlib.py exists when I go into python devshell. So, it seems like the bbappend file is correctly being picked up. The `bitbake-layers show-appends` also confirms that the bbappend file is getting picked up.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first bitbake is failing because bitbake takes recipe names, not runtime package names.

If you really want contextlib split out into a separate package then I'd just cherry-pick 27dbacdb88ee3e79f4c95a779d8a7e8c5c8f941d and b6b9df15a630605619bff060d5073272685058d6 (from oe-core).

The problem here is likely ordering, you're putting PN-contextlib after the manifest inc has taken everything else.  Use PACKAGES =+ to prepend instead of append.

Note that contextlib is packaged without this append, likely in the python-misc package, so I do wonder why so many people desperately want it split out.

Comment: Yes it is definitely an ordering issue. I will try with prepending the package. Do you happen to know the history behind the split. It seems contextlib package is critical as it provides a convenient syntax sugar. Thanks.

Comment: Anything that isn't in a package explicitly goes into -misc.  As new modules got added to Python over the years, some modules didn't get moved to new modules or were left in misc.  contextlib is still packaged, it's just not split out into its own (tiny) package.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this person is also having a similar issue - http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.embedded.yocto.general/21170

I manually verified this. I added the contents of the `python_2.7.3.bbappend` at the end of the `python_2.7.3.bb` file which didn't work.

I then added the contents of the `python_2.7.3.bbappend` at the end of the python-2.7-manifest.inc file which worked.

Comment: So, how would one "extend / modify" the required file defined in a bb file?